# A question on Inverse Image of Thomae function

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

The definition of Thomae function is
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{q},  & \text{if $x=\dfrac{p}{q}$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}$$
where $p\in \mathbb{Z}, q\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\gcd(p,q)=1.$

My question is about inverse image of this function. What is $f^{-1}(1)$? I saw a youtube video, it said $f^{-1}(1)=\mathbb{Z}$. But I think $f^{-1}(1)=\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Well $0=\frac{0}{1}$ and $\gcd(0,1)=1$ so by definition $f(0)=1$, why would you exclude $0$?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. I thought gcd(0,1) is not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comment $f(0)=1.$ I will show you this in a fancier way.

> **Lemma:** Thomae function is periodic with period $1,$ i.e., $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$
> Proof: $x$ is irrational iff so does $x+1,$ and in this case $f(x+1)=f(x)=0.$
> If $x=\frac{p}{q}$ is a rational in the standard form, then $x+1=\frac{p+q}{q}$ is also in the standard form as $\gcd(p+q, q)=\gcd(p,q)=1$ and therefore $f(x+1)=f(x)=\frac{1}{q}.$

As a consequence to this lemma $f(x+n)=f(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$
Now choose $x=0$ and your favorite non-zero integer for $n$ :)